# How to identify country of App Store inside application

Tags: iphone, app-store

my future iOS (iPhone/iPad) application will be available worldwide and needs information from which local App Store it was downloaded.

Searched through apple documentation, stackoverflow, google and apple dev forums and found nothing.

So, what is the way to get such info programmatically (if possible at all)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such a Feature anywhere. I mean, that would require the installed app to be uniquely  identified for each download. Sounds kinda difficult for me.

Comment: the idea is not to provide such info from developer (explicitly specify a country where application will be available) but to get it from apple.

Comment: i know that, but how should apple give you that info? There is no API in there that allows this.

Answer (score 0):

What information do you need from the App Store? iOS has built in feature to detect the language / region of the device, not really sure there is a way to find out which store it was downloaded from.

Comment: Yes, this info (language/region/locale) can suggest the country of App Store but I'd prefer to know for sure.

Comment: Theres no API to check what Store the app came from.